# Creating webpage to retrieve SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created a report using SSRS in sql server 2008 r2,and now i want to create a front end webpage to retrieve the reports depending on the users choice..eg: Giving the user the reports  from start to end date..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are trying to show it in ASP.NET, you need to use the ReportViewer Control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179197%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Provide a custom UI to take in the parameter values parameter and then load the report in an inline frame by passing the parameters using the rc: commands and disable the toolbars if wanted
refer the following : [Using URL Access Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx)